# Can I fail a scenario from BeforeScenario and AfterScenario hooks?

Tags: specflow

Current dealing with an issue with exceptions being raised in hooks. When exceptions are thrown (at least from the "After" hooks), the previous scenario context is not disposed, which causes the log file for future scenarios to become unreadable.

As a temporary fix, I have added a try/catch around the test setup/teardown, however I want to be able to see that something has thrown without browsing the logs. We view the results from Jenkins, so if we could "fail" the test, we would be more likely to spot the issue.

Is there any way of doing this manually, without allowing the exception to be thrown?

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block, do an intentional false assertion like something below..

```
Assert.True(false); //(Xunit)
Assert.IsTrue(false); //(Nunit)
```

This would make your test fail in the hooks without throwing the exception.